# Validating word count tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm working on validating my tinymce editor. At the moment I have it validating by character count which works, but I would like to turn it into sort of like a word count since this is supposed to be the body of an article. So basically they cannot submit an article that is just a few words.

At the moment I have this

```
setup : function(ed) {
     ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
     tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getBody(), 'focusout', function(e, t) {
             var con = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
             var len = con.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").length;
             if(len <=100){
                $('.storyError').text('An artical has to have at least 100 words!');
             }else{
                    $('.storyError').text(' ');
             }
          });
      });
  }
```

after my init that is and this does work, I would just like to count the words instead of the characters. Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go, just replace the selector and take the text however you need :

```
    var count = 0;
    function fn(){
        count++;
        return ' ';
    }
    var x= $('textarea').text().trim();
    console.log(x);
    x= x.replace(/[\s]+/ig,fn);
    //x is now filtered out of extra spaces too !
    var words = count+1;
    count = 0;
    console.log(words);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/FZJng/2/)

in your case it will be :

```
    var count = 0;
    function fn(){
        count++;
        return ' ';
    }

    setup : function(ed) {
             ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
             tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getBody(), 'focusout', function(e, t) {
             var con = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().trim();
             con = con.replace(/[\s]+/ig,fn);
             //var len = con.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").length;
             var words = count+1;
             count = 0;
             if(words <=100){
                $('.storyError').text('An artical has to have at least 100 words!');
             }else{
                $('.storyError').text(' ');
             }

          });
      });
    }
```

or to make everything in one line use this (but it won't filter extra spaces out):

```
var words = con.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you! Just a few things to note your missing a closing bracket on the setup function and if you set the count to 0 before the if statement it's always 0. :)

Comment: you are welcome :) , here added the missing bracket, I know the count should be reset to 0 after the calculation of words is done and that is before the if statement. so zeroing it before the if statement won't affect it.

Comment: hmm thats strange. When I put it in my working code, it only would work if I removed the count before the if statment.

Comment: you actually have to zero it out because if you don't, then if the function is triggered again, the count will add over the old one. I don't see any syntax error around the count. if you find something please tell me so I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy:

1. Create some dummy element in DOM.
2. Let this element hold your data.
3. Use `Node.textContent` or `Node.innerText` to extract textual content from your data (without tags etc.)
4. Split text and count words.

Working example:

```
var data = '<p>First paragraph <strong>with strong</strong></p>',
    dummy = document.createElement( 'div' );

dummy.innerHTML = data;

console.log( ( dummy.textContent || dummy.innerText ).split( /\s+/ ).length );
>>> 4 // no "strong", "p" etc, just text
```

More about [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) on MDN.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I like the idea of how this works, but for some reason I couldn't get this to work with the tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

for tinymce 4.1.4

```
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle').tinymce({
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: "wordcount code charmap paste",
            toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough | removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap | cut copy paste | undo redo | code visualblocks visualchars",
            paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
            paste_remove_styles: true,
            paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
            paste_strip_class_attributes: true,
            menubar: false,
            toolbar_items_size: 'large',
            forced_root_block: "",
            max_word: 5,
            setup: function (ed) {
                ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
                    var writtenWords = $('.mce-wordcount').html();
                    writtenWords = writtenWords.replace("Words: ", "");
                    var maxWord = ed.settings.max_word;
                    var limited = "";
                    var content = ed.getContent();

                    if (writtenWords >= maxWord) {
                        $('.mce-wordcount').css("color", "red");
                        limited = $.trim(content).split(" ", maxWord);
                        limited = limited.join(" ");

                        ed.setContent(limited);
                    } else {
                        $('.mce-wordcount').css("color", "green");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you share how this would look? For instance will this just stop the user from typing or will it throw an error message like the answer above? Also, can you explain what the limited.join is doing and how this affects the tinymce?

Comment: It will prevent you to write and join the words(this is the answer of your second question) if written words are more than max_word.

Comment: Write and join words? I don't think I'm understanding you...why would I worry if the words they write are joined? Are you talking about a word like 'and-this' or a word with a space. Please, I'm trying to understand what you are doing here. Also, I'm not understanding how you would throw an error with this code or how the words are being counted...by a space?

Answer (score -1):

Your solution lies here

https://github.com/AdamScheller/charwordcount

Ok Here is the complete solution.

1. Download the Zip File From the above Link. It is given in the right side bottom
2. Extract the zip folder in the plugins directory which is inside tinymce. So now you shoyld have a directory in your plugins directory named (charwordcount-master)
3. Then

just call the plugin in your code where you are initializing the editor. I am writing the whole head section here

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>charwordcount TinyMCE plugin example</title>
    <script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            plugins: [
                "charwordcount advlist link image lists preview pagebreak",
                "searchreplace code insertdatetime nonbreaking",
                "table textcolor paste textcolor"
            ],
            charwordcount_include_tags: false, // optional, includes HTML tags and entities (like &nbsp;) in count; disabled by default;
            toolbar1: "preview code | restoredraft undo redo | cut copy paste searchreplace | link unlink image | table | subscript superscript | nonbreaking | outdent indent blockquote | bullist numlist",
            toolbar2: "formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
            menubar: false,
            toolbar_items_size: 'small'
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

this is it now you have both the character and word count capability and it will show in the status bar of the editor. It will be applicable for every textarea.

I hope this makes it clear enough otherwise there is also an example in the zip folder it will be in the newly installed folder

**\plugins\charwordcount-master\charwordcount-master\example**

if you have any problem just let me know. This solution will work 100% as I had spend lot of time looking for the solution.

Saurabh Gupta

Comment: It is not clear where is the solution, is it in one of the files or directly on the page ? You should copy paste the related code inside your answer using the "edit" link button just below it. That way, your answer would be more valuable, especially if the link eventually break.

Comment: You should expand your answer to include how op will integrate it

Comment: While plugins are great to use. Sometimes they are not always the right answer. In this case I was really looking for some help with the code I already had in place that was working.

Comment: Can you send me the html part too so i can figure it out. Actually the code is given in the Js file for both the character and the word count. I need to know how you are called the ed function.

Comment: I already figured out the answer to this in June and you can see above how I fixed my issue. I really have no need to go back to this code to add a plug in. I try to avoid plug ins when I can.

Comment: by the way you can just do a character count by grabbing the length and seeing if it less than your desired amount. I am doing so above.

Answer (score -1):

if you are also faced this problem means required validation is not working when you are using tinymce html editor, so i have one solution, please follow it and i hope your problem  solve, Check below code 
install package of tinymce jquery in your application with the use of nuget package
create one model like this
**Model**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter About Company")]
    [Display(Name = "About Company : ")]
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string txtAboutCompany { get; set; }
```

**CSHTML OR VIEW**

```
 <div class="divclass">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
       <span class="field-validation-error" id="AC" style="margin:9px 0 0 57px;">/span>
 </div>
```

And this is jquery

```
$("#BusinessProfile").click(function () {
        var aboutC = $("#txtAboutCompany").val()
        var pinfo = $("#txtProductinfo").val();
        if (aboutC == "" && pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        } else if (aboutC == "") {
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#txtAboutCompany").focus();
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        } else if (pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#txtProductinfo").focus();
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("");
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("");
            //return true;
            $("#bpform").validate();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This post has already been answered with a solution (last year) that worked wonderfully. Why create a completely separate model if you can do this all in jQuery and use less code? What benefits does this have above the above answer?